# How can my local website be visited from outside?

Tags: networking, port-forwarding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Allowing access to localhost page outside network?](https://superuser.com/questions/228975/allowing-access-to-localhost-page-outside-network)

I can visit my site by http://localhost

And I give my friend my ip address like 220.181.6.184,

but they can't browse it by http://220.181.6.184

How to enable this?

Comment: Your web server is likely configured to listen on localhost only. Which web server are you using, on which OS?

Comment: i too have the same question, i m using VS 2008, windows server, with router. What port do i need to open for it, is it same port 80

Comment: I have a static ip

Comment: Your Cable modem or DSL router have a static IP.  You need to take a look at your cable modem or DSL router, and let us know what model / manufacturer it is.  Or use PortForward (www.portforward.com), to look up the model, and set port 80 to forward to your computer.

Comment: Have you got a static ip address of your own ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to set up port forwarding to Port 80 in your DSL router (provided a DSL router is running).

Comment: added comment, plz answer for that too

Answer (score 2):

If you are behind a router, you will have to forward port 80 to your computer's internal IP address. See this guide: http://www.portforward.com/english/applications/port_forwarding/Apache/Apacheindex.htm

Your question does not really describe your current setup in any detail at all.

Comment: added comment, plz answer for that too

Answer (score 0):

You could use Dynamic DNS software. Essentially install a software that will contact the server and figure out your local IP, and then provide an internet address to access it. There are many service providers out there, don't really know which is the best. Here is one I found : http://www.dyndns.com/